# How to add elements into one div until it's width almost equal to another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 containers, one inside the other, and I'm trying to fill the inner container with elements on document.ready so it's width is almost equal to the outer's div width.

It works perfectly with "if" statement on window.resize, but since I need to fill the div on document.ready I'm trying to use "while" and it doesn't work. Why?

Here is the HTML:

```
<style>
    #outer {float: left; width: 500px; background: grey}
    #inner {float: left; width: auto;}
    li {float: left; margin: 0 10px}
</style>


<div id="outer">
    <ul id="inner">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

​

...and JS:

```
function width_check() {
    var ddd = $("#outer").width() - $("#inner").width();
    var sss = 0;

    if (ddd > 100) {
        sss = 1;
    } else { sss = 0 };}​


$(document).ready function() {
    width_check();

    while (sss = 1) {
        $("#inner").append('<li></li>');
        width_check();
                    }        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a scope problem here.

You have a function that defines `var sss = 0`. But the check of `$(document).ready` has its own sss. sss is undefined in this function. Try something like:

```
function width_check()
{
    var ddd = $("#outer").width() - $("#inner").width();
    return ddd > 100;
}​


$(document).ready( function() // check the extra brackets around the function.
{
    while(width_check()) // check the width every time
    {
        $("#inner").append('<li></li>');
    }       
});
```

Comment: `return (ddd > 100);` would be better in `width_check`. It's no need to simulate boolean values with integers.

Comment: @RoToRa True, I just copied his code. There are more things. Like: we have a global function now, which is maybe not needed at all.

Comment: @RoToRa I understand it's such a noobie question, so before asking anybody I tried different ugly things, and that's one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Do like marnix says, and add `display: block;` to your `li`s

Comment: Why do I need "display: block;"?

Comment: Maybe it does not matter because you are using margin which works with inline elements, but you could use width: 20px; display: inline-block; for the same result